# Обобщённый метод

Tags: java

Почему я не могу массив `интов` передать в обобщённый метод класса `Algorithm`?

Цель:найти минимальный элемент массива любого типа.

Код:

```
public class EOl {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Algorithm obj = new Algorithm();
        int[] array = new int[]{1, 6, 4, 8, 12};
        System.out.println(obj.minElement(array));
    }
}

class Algorithm{
    public <T extends Comparable> T minElement(T[] elem){
        if (elem == null || elem.length == 0){
            return null;
        }
        T minimal = elem[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < elem.length; i++){
            if (minimal.compareTo(elem[i]) > 0){
                minimal = elem[i];
            }
        }
        return minimal;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int` - примитив, `extends Comparable` не про него. Тут нужен `Integer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` - один из примитивных типов Java (Ещё есть boolean, byte, char, short, long, float, double). Он не наследуется от базового класса `Object`, и не реализует никакие интерфейсы. Переменные типа `int` не могут принимать значение `null`.

`Integer` - класс-обертка над `int`. `Integer` - наследуется от `Object`, реализует интерфейс `Comparable`. Переменные этого типа могут иметь значение `null`.

В простых ситуациях Java способна прозрачно и незаметно преобразовывать `int` в `Integer`. В вашем случае это не работает, т.к. явно объявлено, что метод `minElement` принимает на вход массив значений типа `T`, который реализует интерфейс `Comparable`.

Кроме того, метод `minElement` может возвращать null. Если попытаться присвоить результат переменной `int`, то есть шанс получить `NullPointerException`.

То есть, в данном случае вам нужно передавать в метод `minElement` не массив `int[]`, а массив `Integer[]`: `Integer[] array = new Integer[]{1, 6, 4, 8, 12};`